# push_back element to vector in class object isn't working

Tags: c++

1. classObject and vector within it.
2. I made a vector of classObject and function that searches classObject with a given int id.
3. Wanted to search certain classObject from listClass and add "apple" inside its wordList but failed. (assume listClass contains classObject with id 1)

```
class classObject { 
 public: 
    int id;
    vector<string> wordList; 
};

vector<classObject> listClass; 

classObject getClassById(int _i) {
    for(auto e : listClass) {
        if(e.id == _i) return e;
    }
} 

classObject example = getClassById(1);

example.wordList.push_back("apple");

cout << getClassById(1).wordList.size();
// returns 0. Supposed to be 1 (added apple)
```

Tried to use `pointer`

```
classObject* getClassById(int _i) {
    for(auto e : listClass) {
        if(e.id == _i) return &e;
    }
} 

classObject example = *getClassById(1);

example.wordList.push_back("apple");
```

Still not working. help!

Comment: Two major problems with `getClassById`: First it returns a pointer to the *local* variable `e`, a pointer which will immediately become invalid; Secondly if nothing is found and the loop ends you don't return *anything*. Both cases leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `example` is never added to `listClass`

Answer (score 0):

`classObject example` is a copy, you need to use `classObject& example` to store a reference and change `getClassById` to return a reference too:

```
classObject& getClassById(int _i) {
  for(auto& e : listClass) {
    if(e.id == _i) return e;
  }
} 

classObject& example = getClassById(1);
```

Now we're left with the problem that `getClassById` doesn't always return a value. You probably have three options to solve this:

1. Throw an exception at the end of `getClassById` when no value is found
2. Return some default object
3. Change the return from a reference to a pointer and return a null pointer

For either of the last two options you'll need to change the calling code to check for the special/null value.

Comment: 4. Return `std::optional`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can't have an optional reference? (I had the same thought but it doesn't work)

Comment: [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)... ;)

Comment: And considering that the original code of the OP copies the object anyway, references might not be needed. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A `std::optional<std::refence_wrapper<classObject>>` doesn't seem much different to a pointer and is very long winded. They do need a reference, the main point of their question is caused by returning a copy which doesn't update the original list when modified

Comment: I agree with Alan here. A pointer already has a no-object state with `nullptr`. Wrapping it in std::optional has 0 benefits and 37 drawbacks (extra letters to type).